# passing props with Link in React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

Hello i'm trying to pass Props to a `Details` Component with the Link Component from React Router. I don't want to display the `Detail` Component  on the page, it should render when a button is clicked but also the url should look like this '/details/KvhNJecsqr6JFMSRTS' when the new Component renders.

```
 class  Card extends Component {
                    render(props){
                    return(
                   <Col xs={12} md={4}>
                    <Thumbnail src="./someiamge">
                      <h3>{this.props.cardHeading}</h3>
                      <p>{this.props.cardDesc}</p>
                        <Button bsStyle="primary">Mieten</Button>&nbsp;
                        <Button bsStyle="default"><Link to='/details' params={{cardId: this.props.cardId}} 'here i wanna pass some props how i do this ?' >Details</Link></Button>
                    </Thumbnail>
                  </Col>

                    )
                  }
                }

export default Card
```

Here is my Router stuff

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <div>
              <Route name='details' path='/details/:cardId' component={Details}/>
            </div>
          </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

hier is my `Details` Component:

```
    class Details extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div >
            <div style={{textAlign: "left"}}>
              <h3>{this.props.cardHeading}</h3>
              <p>{this.props.cardDesc}</p>
              .......
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Details;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If want your new route to be like /details/:cardId, then I guess this should be enough:

```
<Link to={`/details/${this.props.cardId}`} />
```

But, if you want to add some extra properties, then according to [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link), you could pass them in the `location.state`:

```
<Link to={{
  pathname: `/details/${this.props.cardId}`,
  state: { 
    cardHeading: 'This is a heading',
    cardDesc: 'Description'
  }
}}/>
```

Then, in order to access this state in your component, you can use the `this.props.location.state` or `this.props.history.location.state`

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

In your link code it should be this, I believe:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/details', query: { cardId: this.props.cardId } }}/>
```

The Route would be the same as you currently have it.

Comment: doesnt work for me. USage example <Route  path='/app_house_catalog/:auction' component={StartPageHouse} />     ,     <NavLink className="nav-link" to={{
                                pathname: '/app_house_catalog/',
                                query: {
                                    auction : 55
                                }
                                     }} >
     hohohoh
                        </NavLink>  . Yields no param in result