# Problems passing a dynamic link to the table

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-bootstrap-table

I'm using **react-bootstrap-table** here, but every other option is a good deal. I have a big problem inserting a Link to the table. I tried almost everything. I got data coming from a server, so I'm mapping over it and rendering the results. But I need to be able to click on one of them and take that clicked value and passes it onto the second component. I'm able to do do that without using react-bootstrap-tables, but I like them so much, so I was wondering if that's a possibility and if so, can you please help me. Here's an important piece of code.

**sortedReports is an array.**

```
let test = sortedReports.map(item => {
        return (<Link to={{ pathname: '/reports/details', state: { item } }}>
                    <PieChart size="21"/>
                </Link>
                )
        });

return (
        <div className="container">
        <div>
        <header style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
            <h4>The complete list of reports</h4>
            <p style= {{ color: '#48C6EF' }}>Details available by clicking on an icon </p>
            </header>
            <hr />
        </div>

<div className="col-md-10">
        <BootstrapTable
          data={ sortedReports }
          pagination>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='year'>Year</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataFormat = { this.colFormatter} dataField='month'>Month</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='ukupno_plata'>Full salary</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='bruto_ukupno' isKey={true}>Full gross</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='bruto_plata'>Bruto</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='neto_plata'>Neto</TableHeaderColumn>          
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='topli_obrok'>Neto</TableHeaderColumn>                    
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField='doprinosi'>Taxes</TableHeaderColumn> 
          <TableHeaderColumn **dataField={test}**>Details</TableHeaderColumn>
```

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287855/passing-props-with-link-in-react-router?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Yes, you're totally right, but How can I pass something like this --> 

`let test = sortedReports.map(item => {
        return (<Link to={{ pathname: '/reports/details', state: { item } }}>
                    <PieChart size="21"/>
                </Link>
                )
        });`

... to a `<td>` element while still having the ability of pagination. I'm able to do one or the other, but not both.

Cheers.

Comment: The big question is, how can I pass `<Link to={{ pathname: '/reports/details', state: { item } }}` into a table with the ability of pagination ?

Thank you for reaching out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy and pretty straightforward **now**, but at that time it gave me headaches :)

What I did is, I used a library called `react-feather` to display icons, wrapped a `<Link />` tag around it, and passed in the relevant data to pass it to the next component. And in the next component I accessed it like this: 
`const { data} = this.props.history.location.state;`

```
const {yearsData, monthsData, netData, grossData, mealsData, taxData, handSalaryData, employeeNum} = this.state.currentSession;

    // Preparing the data for rendering
    const dataTable = yearsData
        .map((item, idx) => {
            let yearX = item;
            let monthX = monthsData[idx];
            let dev = {};
            data.relMonth = monthX;
            data.relYear = yearX;
            return (
                <tr key={yearX + monthX}>
                    <td>{item}</td>
                    <td>{monthsData[idx]}</td>
                    <td>{netData[idx]}</td>
                    <td>{grossData[idx]}</td>
                    <td>{mealsData[idx]}</td>
                    <td>{taxData[idx]}</td>
                    <td>{handSalaryData[idx]}</td>
                    <td>{employeeNum[idx]}</td>

                   // Here is where the 'magic' happens

                    <td className="table-actions">
                        <Link to={{ pathname: `/reports/details`, state: { data } }}>
                            <Activity size="20"/>
                        </Link>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )});
```